# VS Code not loading tasks and "Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Sometimes when I open vscode and try to build (ctrl-shift-b) it says no build task to run, despite me having a `./.vscode/tasks.json`. This happens with all workspaces on the machine. Reloading the window or just waiting and trying again can sometimes make things work again.

[image]

[image]

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build QMK",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "qmk compile -kb derbard -km default",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "clear": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Flash QMK",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "qmk flash -kb derbard -km default",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Build QMK"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try to configure a new task, it opens my existing tasks.json but doesn't do anything, probably because there's a build task already there. If I manually run the task (ctrl-shift-p, Run Task) it gives a rather confusing error: "Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided."

[image]

What does this even mean? I'm hesitant to file a bug as I don't have a clean repro environment.

This has happened ever since updating Fedora (35 to 37). I currently have this package installed: `code.x86_64 1.77.3-1681292829.el7 @code`

Comment: (loosely) related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2506

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily fixed this by cutting `.vscode` folder, pasting it anywhere and then re-pasting it in the vscode project folder.

I definitively fixed this by adding the `group` option to the `tasks.json` file under the `build label`:

```json
  {
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*/*.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        ,"group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
```